# When to use numpy.random.randn(...) and when numpy.random.rand(...)?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning

In my deep learning exercise i had to initialize one parameter D1 of same size as A1 so what i did is:

```
D1 = np.random.randn(A1.shape[0],A1.shape[1])
```

But after computing further equations when i checked the results they didn't matched then after proper reading the doc i discovered that they have said to initialize D1 using rand instead of **randn**;

```
D1 = np.random.rand(A1.shape[0],A1.shape[1])
```

But they didn't specified the reason for it as the code is working in both the cases and also there was a doc for that exercise so I figured out the error, but **how**, **when** and **why** to choose out of these two?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference between [`rand`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) and [`randn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html) is (besides the letter `n`) that `rand` returns random numbers sampled from a [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) over the interval [0,1), while `randn` instead samples from a [normal (a.k.a. Gaussian) distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with a mean of 0 and a variance of 1.

In other words, the distribution of the random numbers produced by `rand` looks like this:

[image: Uniform distribution]

In a uniform distribution, all the random values are restricted to a specific interval, and are evenly distributed over that interval.  If you generate, say, 10000 random numbers with `rand`, you'll find that about 1000 of them will be between 0 and 0.1, around 1000 will be between 0.1 and 0.2, around 1000 will be between 0.2 and 0.3, and so on.  And *all* of them will be between 0 and 1 — you won't ever get any outside that range.

Meanwhile, the distribution for `randn` looks like this:

[image: Normal distribution]

The first obvious difference between the uniform and the normal distributions is that the normal distribution has no upper or lower limits — if you generate enough random numbers with `randn`, you'll eventually get one that's as big or as small as you like (well, subject to the limitations of the floating point format used to store the numbers, anyway).  But most of the numbers you'll get will still be fairly close to zero, because the normal distribution is not flat: the output of `randn` is a lot more likely to fall between, say, 0 and 0.1 than between 0.9 and 1, whereas for `rand` both of these are equally likely.  In fact, as the picture shows, about 68% of all `randn` outputs fall between -1 and +1, while 95% fall between -2 and +2, and about 99.7% fall between -3 and +3.

These are completely different probability distributions.  If you switch one for the other, things are almost certainly going to break.  If the code doesn't simply crash, you're almost certainly going to get incorrect and/or nonsensical results.

Comment: Thanks but can you please tell with any example where one will fit over another?

Comment: Well, if you need uniformly distributed random numbers, then `rand` is better. If you need normally distributed numbers, `randn` is better. They're different tools for different jobs. It's kind of like asking which is better, a hammer or a screwdriver; it depends on whether you need to drive a nail or a screw.

Comment: Check this https://pastebin.com/ucN3sJz4 , where's the uniformity and non-uniformity ?

Comment: @sak: Generate a few more values (say, 100 or 1000 or 10000) and plot a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) of them. You'll see it.